# How to use google line chart two different length arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a Google Line Chart, where each line may have a different number of data points. This is my array format one with length 2 and one with length 3 . I dont know how to solve this problem , any help is appreciable

```
Array [ Date 2018-05-04T18:30:00.000Z, 45 ]
Array [ Date 2018-05-22T18:30:00.000Z, 234, 234, 234 ]
```

This is the code that i am using for plotting the graph , here both my columns and rows are dynamic.

```
for (var k = 0; k < data1.queryA.length; k++) {
  data.addColumn('number', data1.queryA[k].keyword);
}
for (var i = 0; i < data1.query.length; i++) {
  var arr = [];
  alert(data1.query[i].date.length);
  for (var j = 0; j < data1.query[i].date.length; j++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(data1.query[i].date[j].page));
  }
  var test = [new Date(data1.query[i].datee)];
  console.log(test.concat(arr));
  data.addRow(test.concat(arr));
}
```

Comment: Is the first element in the array supposed to be the `x` value of the data points, or a date-like *label* for your data points?

Comment: x value of datapoint

Comment: Does the second data point contain duplicate data, or are there three lines that have the `234` value on that date?

Comment: those values may vary or same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row needs to have a length exactly matching the number of columns. You can "right pad" your rows with `null` values to show missing data points:

```js
const data = [
  [ new Date("2018-05-04T18:30:00.000Z"), 45 ],
  [ new Date("2018-05-05T18:30:00.000Z"), 45, 12 ],
  [ new Date("2018-05-22T18:30:00.000Z"), 234, 234, 234 ]
];

const padNull = (size, data) =>
  data.map(r =>
    [...r, ...Array(size - r.length).fill(null)]
  );
  
  
console.log(padNull(4, data));
```

If you don't know how many columns you need, you need to find the largest data set:

```js
const data = [
  [ new Date("2018-05-04T18:30:00.000Z"), 45 ],
  [ new Date("2018-05-05T18:30:00.000Z"), 45, 12 ],
  [ new Date("2018-05-22T18:30:00.000Z"), 234, 234, 234 ]
];

const columnCount = Math.max(...data.map(r => r.length));
console.log(columnCount);
```